# How to run the mysqldump.exe command?

Tags: windows, mysql, wamp

I've this program at

> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\bin

, but it immediately disappears when I try to run it. It also doesn't work as a command of mySQL console interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open up a command prompt (CLI) and run the command.  It isn't intended to be an interactive program.  Instead it is supposed to be used within a script or called by another program with lots of [command line options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) telling mysqldump which operations it is supposed to perform.

Comment: in cmd.exe : 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @kowalt did you try using mysqldumps full path when you tried to run it?